# How to select Point In Time record

Tags: mysql, point-in-time

I have a MariaDB 10.2.21.

My table contains records that include a 'ChangeDate' field like this: '2019-09-18 10:57:26'.

I want to do a SELECT based on a timestamp, and get the **nearest previous** record to return.

This allows me to do a 'point-in-time' selection providing me with field values as they were at that moment.

I seeked StackOverflow but do no recognize a proper solution.
Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following Query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE ChangeDate < '2019-09-18 10:57:26' 
 ORDER 
    BY ChangeDate DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Never realized it was that trivial. Thanks!